# Safari 6 debugger -- view recorded request/response headers

Tags: safari

I'm not sure if I'm misssing something or what, but I can't seem to find the request/response headers for anything except the most recent request even when recording networking requests in Safari 6.0.1's debugger.

I did the follow:

1. Enabled `Recording` under Instruments
2. Navigated to a page
3. Viewed the initial Document request and saw it's request/response headers
4. Submitted a form on that page which redirected me to a different site

Now when I look at the network requests, I can view the requests/response headers for the most recent request made by the browser but it seems to have lost the headers for the requests previous to that.

Comment: In 6.0.3, I can see the request and response headers, but I can't see any way to view the actual content of the request/response.

Answer (score 7):

An old question, but this still stumped me for a bit.  Hit the 'Resource' button in the top right corner and a sidebar slides out from the right with header information

Answer (score 1):

In Safari 9 I found my "Details Sidebar" hiding behind a small button on the right-hand side of the Network panel. (Keyboard shortcut: Opt-Cmd-R)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Looks like in Safari 6.0.4 you can see the full request/response headers and you can double click the line containing the request to see the contents of the response.

Comment: Out-dated and inaccurate answer.